# Ignore [clang-diagnostic-error] clang-tidy caused by 3rd party headers

Tags: c++, header-files, linter, clang-tidy

I am using clang-tidy as a "linter" tool in development. I started to integrate 3rd party software into my code and when I include their header files using:

```
-I/path/to/include
```

tons of errors are generated, I haven't even `#include` the headers yet.

```
error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [clang-diagnostic-error]
...
/path/to/include/wchar.h:81:1: error: unknown type name 'wint_t' [clang-diagnostic-error]
wint_t fgetwc(FILE *__stream);
^
/path/to/include/wchar.h:81:15: error: unknown type name 'FILE' [clang-diagnostic-error]
wint_t fgetwc(FILE *__stream);
              ^
...
```

I compile my program using:

```
/usr/bin/clang-tidy-4.0 /path/to/main.cpp -checks=-*,cppcoreguidelines* -- -lang-c++ -I/path/to/include -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Werror -O0 -g -D<define variables>
```

It seems that these "clang-diagnostic-errors" do not stop compilation, as it continues to compile and runs fine. Is there a flag to turn this error off/suppress it? I do not want to see it since I did not write these header files.

If I get rid of the argument `-I/path/to/include` everything compiles fine with no errors.

Comment: [Potentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638293/ignore-system-headers-in-clang-tidy)

Comment: I've had success using `-header-filter`. [Docs](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#using-clang-tidy)

Comment: Doesn't `-header-filter` make clang-tidy check those header files? I do not want to check them at all, which I thought was the default?

Comment: Yes by default it should ignore all headers, although I'm only familiar with newer versions. Maybe when passing -I directly it behaves differently then using `compile-commands.json`?

Comment: `clang-diagnostic-error` seems to be special and is not a regular check. Header filtering doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Use `-isystem/path/to/include` instead of `-I`. This suppresses all warnings from that file and everything it includes.

Comment: Good question! Seems to be an easy problem to solve, still have no clue how to get rid of this errors.

Answer (score 6):

There is **no way to ignore** **`clang-diagnostic-error`** since it's basically a compiler error.

For `clang-tidy` to work the analyzed code needs to be compile-able by the `clang` backend to generate an AST(Abstract syntax tree).

The problem is you are including headers that cannot be compiled by clang (I'm guessing windows headers intended for MSVC).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would not break something later, so just at your own risk. I managed to "solve" this (because it was just a matter of having an error on the Problems list) on VSCode:

```
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args": [
  "--extra-arg=-ferror-limit=1"
]
```

This makes clang-tidy tell the compiler to throw just one error and give up. So clang-tidy will parse whatever is left.

I know was for VSCode, but the argument can be used in other IDEs.

Answer (score -1):

Try to prevent infinite loops. I had the problem once when I had a window running in SDL2 and when I simply linked a second condition with "|", it worked. I think the Problem goes with VS Code Debugger that it thinks, that a Loop is infinite. I don’t know if the problem caused by VS Code, but my solution worked

Comment: Is this answer a solution to the question? The OP doesn't even mention VS Code.